# Past progressive (continuous) and hypotheses

Tags: past-continuous

*Emergencies come up because you don't plan them. But a lot of them you could maybe have done research and seen on the horizon, discontent with employees, a product that **wasn't working**, something coming up that you would've been able to prevent.*

Could someone explain me usage of Past Progressive in the example above? As the topic title suggests, I think that it indicates the hypothetical situation. If my guess is correct, please show me some references to good grammar text books where this rule is explained.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just an example of a situation in the past which 'you' (the owner of a business) should have been able to foresee. One of your products 'wasn't working' (wasn't selling well, or had a lot of problems). It was an ongoing situation in the past, hence past continuous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example paragraph you include uses a number of contractions and omissions, presumably to try to make it easier to read.

What is meant by the phrase "a product **wasn't working**" in the context of this paragraph should be expanded to be:

> an issue arising with a product which you knew wasn't working

So the event which constitutes the emergency happens in an ongoing situation which is known about.  So the *event* is not being described in the past continuous but rather the situation which was ongoing when it happened.

So I can see that it can be confusing that an emergency (which is an event that happens at a point in time) appears to be being described as being an ongoing situation which lasts for a period of time.